# why does npm install dependences that are not listed in my package.json file?

Tags: dependency-injection, npm, package

I'm having trouble finding an answer to this problem.

tl;dr... I just ran `npm update npm -g` before starting a new Node/Express project.  When I run `npm install` for this project, npm installs a ton of new dependencies that aren't listed in my package.json folder.  I've never even seen many of these before.

- package.json file: http://puu.sh/khZm6/8233ab02a0.png
- node_modules folder: http://puu.sh/khZid/a5eade9ce1.png

What's going on here -- why is npm installing all these dependencies and how do I fix this?

I even tested `npm install` on an older project from last week and it did similar behavior.

ps - someone mentioned that even dependencies need dependencies. like this? http://puu.sh/ki1GW/cfead489ef.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too many npm modules are installed after execute "npm install"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794319/too-many-npm-modules-are-installed-after-execute-npm-install)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those are dependencies of your dependencies. Think of it like a tree structure, with your project as the root node. Everything in the tree needs to be downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

This was answered here: [Too many npm modules are installed after execute “npm install”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33794337/5787277), but basically there is nothing wrong. The unfamiliar packages are the dependencies of your packages. **Previously, they were  nested inside the package's folder** and therefore often went unnoticed. Since NPM version 3.0.0 they are no longer being nested.

From the NPM 3.0.0 release notes:

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.