# Too many npm modules are installed after execute "npm install"

Tags: json, node.js, npm

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "thumbnaillist-gulp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-react": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "react-script-loader": "0.0.1",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.6.1"
  }
}
```

The weird thing is that after I execute "npm install", besides the modules listed in the dependencies field, other modules are also installed, such as

```
drwxr-xr-x  14 xxx  wheel   476B Nov 18 18:41 acorn
drwxr-xr-x   7 xxx  wheel   238B Nov 18 18:41 amdefine
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 ansi-green
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 ansi-regex
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 ansi-styles
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 ansi-wrap
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 anymatch
drwxr-xr-x   9 xxx  wheel   306B Nov 18 18:41 archy
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 arr-diff
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 arr-flatten
drwxr-xr-x   5 xxx  wheel   170B Nov 18 18:41 array-differ
drwxr-xr-x   8 xxx  wheel   272B Nov 18 18:41 array-filter
drwxr-xr-x   9 xxx  wheel   306B Nov 18 18:41 array-map
drwxr-xr-x   9 xxx  wheel   306B Nov 18 18:41 array-reduce
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 array-slice
drwxr-xr-x   5 xxx  wheel   170B Nov 18 18:41 array-uniq
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 array-unique
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 arrify
drwxr-xr-x   8 xxx  wheel   272B Nov 18 18:41 asn1.js
drwxr-xr-x  10 xxx  wheel   340B Nov 18 18:41 assert
drwxr-xr-x  10 xxx  wheel   340B Nov 18 18:41 ast-types
drwxr-xr-x   9 xxx  wheel   306B Nov 18 18:41 astw
drwxr-xr-x   9 xxx  wheel   306B Nov 18 18:41 async-each
drwxr-xr-x  11 xxx  wheel   374B Nov 18 18:41 balanced-match
drwxr-xr-x   8 xxx  wheel   272B Nov 18 18:41 base62
drwxr-xr-x   9 xxx  wheel   306B Nov 18 18:41 base64-js
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 beeper
drwxr-xr-x   6 xxx  wheel   204B Nov 18 18:41 binary-extensions
drwxr-xr-x  10 xxx  wheel   340B Nov 18 18:41 bn.js
drwxr-xr-x   7 xxx  wheel   238B Nov 18 18:41 brace-expansion
drwxr-xr-x   7 xxx  wheel   238B Nov 18 18:41 braces
drwxr-xr-x   7 xxx  wheel   238B Nov 18 18:41 brorand
drwxr-xr-x  13 xxx  wheel   442B Nov 18 18:41 browser-pack
drwxr-xr-x   7 xxx  wheel   238B Nov 18 18:41 browser-resolve
drwxr-xr-x  12 xxx  wheel   408B Nov 18 18:41 browserify
drwxr-xr-x  17 xxx  wheel   578B Nov 18 18:41 browserify-aes
drwxr-xr-x   8 xxx  wheel   272B Nov 18 18:41 browserify-cipher
drwxr-xr-x   7 xxx  wheel   238B Nov 18 18:41 browserify-des
drwxr-xr-x   8 xxx  wheel   272B Nov 18 18:41 browserify-rsa
drwxr-xr-x  16 xxx  wheel   544B Nov 18 18:41 browserify-sign
drwxr-xr-x   8 xxx  wheel   272B Nov 18 18:41 browserify-zlib
drwxr-xr-x  11 xxx  wheel   374B Nov 18 18:41 buffer
drwxr-xr-x  11 xxx  wheel   374B Nov 18 18:41 buffer-xor
```

Any hint on this? Is my NPM broken? Or I did not write a `package.json` in a correct way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No there's nothing wrong, NPM now installs all dependencies to the root modules folder unless there is a version conflict. All those other modules you are seeing are dependencies of the modules you installed.

From the [NPM 3.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0):

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

Comment: Hi, Alex: 
Thanks. Seems like NPM try to want make things clean and independent? It just make my several test projects big. ^_^.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this @Alexander. I wonder what's the benefit of storing all dependencies inside the project instead of caching the ones which are not "project-specific" in a temp directory...

Comment: I put webpack into the node_modules directory with `npm install webpack` then get 341 packages. did you mean webpack depends on 341 packages?

Comment: @inherithandle Yes. It currently has 22 direct dependencies listed in the package.json, but those packages also depend on other packages in turn, which nay also depend on other packages, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I hope Alexander O'Mara answer is helpful for you If you still want or for those who want to use dependencies like older version

you can use

**npm install --legacy-bundling**

If you always want use

**npm set legacy-bundling=true**

and use can run as usual

**npm install**